# Google Sheets ordering by dropdown choice

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I'm completely new to sheets and am currently trying to set up a filter for a column. The column is set up to use dropdowns to pick a string.

What I'm trying to do is order it by the text, but not alphabetically. In the sheet shown I'm trying to filter it so that General shows, then Major General, Brigade General, etc etc. I'm not even sure if it's possible with filters at this rate.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mk0cV-Di-11oD_rEoGyShRL4PeR9kZccR3hBFdNiuKc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would probably be to create a `Sort key` column by using the `match()` function.

Choose **View > Freeze > 2 rows** and put this formula in cell `B2`:

```
=vstack( 
  "Sort key", 
  arrayformula(iferror(match( 
    E3:E, 
    { "General", "Major General", "Brigade General", "Raid Captain", "Active Duty", "Commander", "Lieutenant", "Sergeant", "Corporal", "Private" }, 
    0 
  ))) 
)
```

Then choose **Data > Sort sheet > Sort sheet by column B**.

See
[vstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13191461),
[arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093275),
[iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304)
and
[match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).

Comment: It would be nice if you explain how and why this works.